# primary menu htmlisation

Tags: html, css, menu

How can I htmlise the attached image with using only css?

If it is not possible with pure css, then how can I do it with an image at-least[image: Primary menu]

Comment: you are not gone get the arrows with pure css. the rest can be done. have you done a css menu before, like a regular menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not really a question, but rather you want us to write the code for you. I'd recommend you to google "css breadcrumb" and take a look at what others have done to construct a similar design. Take a look at [this article](http://www.red-team-design.com/css3-breadcrumbs) for example.

Comment: :) I got it and my template is so perfect now